# How to add complete borders on a flexbox container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to add borders around flexbox containers on my webpage project when the media query hits a large screen size.  I want these borders to connect together to create a table look.  However I can not get this to work.  I have also tried the `<hr>` tag.  If anyone has a suggestion on how to approach this it would be appreciated.  I am wanting the borders to appear around the members section recent activity and settings / message user section.

The code and been seen in this JSfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/TLXL/9wkxts04/

```
  /*********************************
 Media Queries For Large Screen Size
***********************************/

@media (min-width: 1280px){  


/*************************
New Members Styles 
*************************/

.member {
    height: 120px;
    width: 650px;  
   position: relative;
}

.container1 {
        height: 150px;
    }

.member h4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    right: 10%;

}

 .member h3 {
  margin-top:-5px;
    }


.b h4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 99%;
    right: 3%;
    color: #0084b4;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

/*************************
Message User Styles
*************************/
 #buttonBox {
     justify-content: space-around; 

    }

#messageUser{
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;

}


#messageUser input {
   width: 500px;

}

#messageUser textarea {
    height: 225px;
    width: 500px;

}

#messageUser button {
    width: 500px;

}


/*************************
Setings Styles
*************************/

#settings {
 width: 500px;

}

#settings h1 {
        margin-left: -10px;
    }

#settings select {
    width: 500px;
}

.settingsButton {
    width: 500px;
}

    }



    Thank you for your help.
```

Comment: can you narrow your problem ?

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/e8sndzn4/

Comment: Hello, than you for your help.  I need it to look more like this https://jsfiddle.net/e8sndzn4/  but I do not need the side borders.

Comment: just remove  border-right on last child

Comment: when I try on my project I end up with a margin in the middle (the two columns are not connected in the middle ) and I can not get the border to go to the end of the page.

Comment: probably your flexbox does not grow

Comment: ok.  I have set widths on my columns.  If I remove these would that help? Is there anything I can do to make it grow?